# html rendering inside array_push

Tags: php, array-push

I am trying to pass html (image tag) inside an array_push:

```
array_push($result, array("id"=>$value, "label"=>'<img src="images/image.jpg" alt="">'.$value, "value"=>strip_tags($key)));
```

The problem is that the html is rendered in the page like this:

```
&lt;img src="images/image.jpg" alt=""&gt;
```

so I get just text:

```
<img src="images/image.jpg" alt="">
```

instead of an image.

I process the array $result with json_encode:

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: how is the result processed before rendering?

Comment: Could you tell us what you're doing to render the HTML?

Comment: @Alp - I echo the $result through an array_to_json function: echo array_to_json($result);

Comment: That's not a native PHP function, please show us its code.

Comment: You HTML encoded it somewhere. Make a testcase please. You don't seem to have narrowed down the issue at all.

Comment: I'm sure you know this, but there is already a `json_encode` function in PHP

Comment: No @thetaiko, I didn't know that. I will use this now. Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using something like `htmlentities()` or `addslashes()` in your render function. Without, it should work.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, array_push() is converting HTML entities similar to the htmlentities() function. I've never looked into that behavior before, but a simple solution would be when you pop the HTML data from you array, process it with html_entity_decode() before output.

Comment: -1: No, `array_push` does not do that. And you should fix the problem, not mask it after-the-fact.